# Populate data back to form in Kentico

Tags: kentico

Here's what I'd like to do but not sure how to. I have a form that's like a typical doctor/school form, where the form has 2 sections: [1] Section 1 at the top is for user (with standard fields like First Name, Last Name etc.), and [2] Section 2 at the bottom is for Admin/Office use only (with fields like Reviewed by, Approved/Not Approved etc.)

what I was able to do is to process Section 1 where I got **ALL** users' submission and display all their data on a webpage using a RepeaterWithCustomQuery. That's pretty basic. But in order to do what described above, I *guess* that I'll need to pull the submitted data and populate them back to Section 1 of the form (maybe as readonly data at this time) and then the Office/Admin staff can fill in Section 2.

I hope I made sense and hope that someone can point me to the right direction. I only use Portal Engine, no access to file system or backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your issue you want to have some sort of an editor for biz form data. Similar to what you have in the admin. And the problem is that you don't have access to backend. :( Such thing is available for custom table data (there is web part), but not for biz form data. There is no ready to use web part. Here is old topic on that https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/how-to-edit-the-information-of-a-record-using-the-bizform-layout.

you want to have something like the admin page for editing form records:

```
/CMSModules/BizForms/Tools/BizForm_Edit_EditRecord.aspx?formID=7&formRecordID=1
```

but customized :(. I'd say without back end access the only options I see:

1. Create a new role "Biz Form Editor" (or use existing) that has rights only to edit biz
   form data. So all your people who do "validation" part must have a
   Kentico account with role "Biz Form Editor".
2. Add link above to your repeater with appropriate record id.

P.S. There are special code names for alternative forms (https://docs.kentico.com/k8/configuring-kentico/creating-alternative-forms/code-names-of-automatically-used-alternative-forms). If you create an alternative form with special name **update**  the system will automatically load it when you edit the record.

Comment: Thank you Peter! This and your response (also from you!) for another question will likely enough to get me going. The response I mentioned is https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/show-submitted-form-data-on-seperate-page-for-print.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understood correctly your question. But what you need is to use alternative forms. So the idea is that one form is for "registration" and the 2nd one for "validation".
So in your registration form you show only firstName, lastName etc and you don't show "validation" fields. In the validation form you show firstName, lastname etc as label and show textboxes for validation fields.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I guess that'll be the way to go, but I don't really know how to populate the data back to the "registration" portion of the form - as you pointed out - by using portal engine (without having access to the file system). The solutions I've seen so far required access to edit files on the backend. Maybe I missed something....